# Chrome for Android 28: HTML Canvas RadialGradient renders incorrectly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, radial-gradients

Chrome Version : 28.0.`500.94
Operating System Android:4.1.1

The radial gradient function does not work properly.

```
var rad = ctx.createRadialGradient(x, y, 1, x, y, r);
rad.addColorStop(0, "#000000");
rad.addColorStop(1, "#FFFFFF");
ctx.fillStyle = rad;
ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
ctx.fill();
```

results in a solid circle.
Other browsers on Android (and Chrome Desktop as well) render it correctly.

Example:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/eDnQL/2/show/

Does anybody recognize this ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this fixes your problem, but I also had problems using createRadialGradient on Chrome 34 on Android devices.

For me, it only worked correctly if the 3rd argument (inner circle radius) was 0.

```js
// Notice the third argument (start circle radius) MUST be 0 
// for createRadialGradient to work correctly on Chrome Android
var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(x1, y1, 0, x2, y2, r2);
```

Comment: My gradient was showing up as a square, this fixed the issue for me.